# Auto-synchronize an upload directory

Tags: file-manager

Does anyone know a way to automatically synchronize a file directory? Possibly through a cron?

I need to have an image manipulation done to the member photo directory, and I don't see a way to do that automatically through the Members module.

Using EE 2.6.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in way to do this. You'd need to build an add-on that triggers the manipulations, similar to how it's triggered when the images are uploaded through the control panel.

An easier way to handle this might be to do the resizing on the frontend using the [CE Image](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image) plugin. The manipulations get generated when they are needed, so you don't need to worry about a cron job to process new images for you.

Comment: I had posted this to the EE forums as well, and one guy suggested the same thing. I've already bought CE Image, and it is incredible. I do not know how I have missed it, but it's now in my default plugin set. Thanks Jeremy!